# Force.com Site: SSL exception javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: force.com-sites, ssl

**Situation**

I enabled SSL for one of our Force.com Sites. The website is available and all SSL certs are working fine.

I noticed that SSL doesn't work in case you are using getContent(). As you can see below I implemented a APEX Class:

```
public with sharing class SalesforceTestCase {
    public String content {get; set;}
    public SalesforceTestCase() {
        try
        {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/MyPage');
        content = pr.getContent().toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            content = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And in addition a Visualforce page to show the variable content.

```
<apex:page controller="SalesforceTestCase" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
    {!content}
</apex:page>
```

**Test case**

It works fine without HTTPS:

http://www.die-akademie.de/SalesforceTestCase

But in the moment you are using HTTPS the site fails:

https://www.die-akademie.de/SalesforceTestCase

**Question**

How can I fix this issue? Does it have anything to do with getContent()?

Answer (score 1):

It has a very simple Solution.

For the site https://www.die-akademie.de/SalesforceTestCase upload SSL certificate which is **CA signed**. All other circuits are rejected by Salesforce or behave in unexpected way.

Error standard description:

> When the peer was not able to identify itself (for example; no
>   certificate, the particular cipher suite being used does not support
>   authentication, or no peer authentication was established during SSL
>   handshaking) this exception is thrown.

[image: issue]

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. You are right. Except: The certificate is CA signed. This can be simply verified by acting the page https://www.die-akademie.de/SalesforceTestCase. The certificate was signed by AlphaSSL.

Comment: @ChristianDeckert did you try accessing the site in browser. I got error as shown in answer.

Comment: which android version? And which device?

Comment: ChristianDeckert it is Android 5.0.1 running on Samsung Galaxy Note 4.

Comment: @ChristianDeckert Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same issue. PageReference getContent seems to fail when using a custom SSL certificate, even when it is CA-Signed.

Comment: The intermediate certificate was not provided.

Comment: @ChristianDeckert I am having the same issue,  someone else did the certificate for me, what do you mean by The intermediate certificate was not provided?, do I need to resign this certificate and somewere in the process specify the intermediate certificate? and what will this value be? thank you